# Displaying an array in a UL using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help displaying my javascript array within a UL html element.

I have been trying to figure this out for the last 4 days and I am not getting it right.

See my code below:

```
function load() {
  let favLanguages = ["html", "css", "javascript", "go", "ruby"];

  // create ul element and set its attributes.
  let ul = document.createElement("ul");

  for (i = 0; i <= favLanguages.length; i++);

  {
    let li = document.createElement("li"); // create li element.

    li.innerHTML = favLanguages[i]; // assigning text to li using array value.

    document.getElementById(1);

    ul.appendChild(li); // append li to ul.
  }
}
```

html

```
 <body onload="load()">

    <h1>My favourite languages:</h1>

    <ul id="1"></ul>
```

I would really appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: check the semicolon after the for statement:  for (i = 0; i <= favLanguages.length; i++);

Comment: and append the list    document.getElementById("1").append(ul);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much there. You had a couple of issues:

- You already have specified a `ul` element within your HTML. You don't need to re-create it again by doing `document.createElement('ul')`, just select the `ul` instead
- You had your `ul` element's id as the number `1`. When you tried to select the `ul` by doing document.getElementById(1)`, that will not work. You need to pass in the string of the id. I rename it to 'one' to fix it.
- In your `for(...)` loop, you had a semi colon (`;`) after `for(...);`. That will not work. I removed the semi colon for you.
- You last line of code `ul.appendChild(li)` is the only thing you need to do after you set your `innerHTML`. You already have the `ul` in the dom, so just append your new elements to that.

Example:

```js
function load() {
  const favLanguages = ["html", "css", "javascript", "go", "ruby"];

  // Get a refrerence to the UL
  const ul = document.getElementById('one');

  for (i = 0; i <= favLanguages.length; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement("li"); // create li element.

    li.innerHTML = favLanguages[i]; // assigning text to li using array value.

    ul.appendChild(li); // append li to ul.
  }
}

load();
```

```html
<h1>My favourite languages:</h1>

<ul id="one"></ul>
```

Comment: Instead of i <= favLanguages.length, use i < favLanguages.length as it is resulting in an extra list item called undefined

Comment: You are correct. You should fix your answer then. I don't want to change too much of the code so the OP is still familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

The second line has an inline comment disrupting the code on that line. So, the `let ul = document.createElement("ul");` is not read by the JS engine. It can be fixed by moving the comment *after* the code.

Your for loop **and** your function declaration have a semicolon terminating it. Try fixing it like below:

```
function load() { 
let favLanguages = ["html", "css", "javascript", "go", "ruby"]

let ul = document.createElement("ul"); // create ul element and set its attributes. 

for (i = 0; i <= favLanguages.length; i++) { let li = document.createElement("li"); // create li element.

li.innerHTML = favLanguages[i]; // assigning text to li using array value.

document.getElementById(1);

ul.appendChild(li); // append li to ul.
} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I have tried using the code you suggested but my list still  for some reason does not populate, is there perhaps something missing in my html?        <body onload="load()">
                  <h1>My favourite languages:</h1>
                    <ul id="1"></ul>

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function(){
  // init arr
  let favLanguages = ["html", "css", "javascript", "go", "ruby"];
  // get ul element after document loaded: window.onload
  let ulNode = document.getElementById("a1");
  
  
  // create ul element and set its attributes.
  let ul = document.createElement("ul");

  for (let i = 0; i < favLanguages.length; i++){
    let li = document.createElement("li"); // create li element.

    li.innerText = favLanguages[i];  //inrHTML if you have new element

    ulNode.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>My favourite languages:</h1>

    <ul id="a1"></ul>
```